# Retrieve data from many to many relationship in asp.net mvc linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have problem retrieving data in many to many relationship using linq.

I have 3 tables

- `Employee`
- `role`
- `RoleInemployee`

The third table has two columns: `empid` and `roleid`

An employee can assigned to multiple roles are stored in third table or you can say single role assigned to multiple employee.

I just want to retrieve employee who have particular role id using linq.

I'm using navigation property in employee model like

```
public virtual ICollection<Role> role {get;set;}
```

This navigation property give me  role for particular employee but I want to retrieve employees data  which is having  a particular role  is assigned.

Can any body help?

Comment: see edited answer... for edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count has an overload with a predicate as parameter, so you can do

```
   var count =  db.Employees.Count(emp=> emp.role.Any(r=> r.Id == 12));
```

**Edit**

to get employees with a particular role

```
var employees = db.Employees.Where(emp => emp.role.Any(r => r.Id == 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly you want to get the number of employees set to a particular role id using LINQ.

If your entity framework Employee class has a list of roles included -- you can do the following with your list of employees where 123 is the RoleID you are looking for:

```
employeeList.Where(x => x.Roles.Where(y => y.RoleID == 123)).Count();
```

**EDIT:** Removed RoleInEmployee code

Comment: For second solution : in EF, RoleInEmployee class probably doesn't exist (this is an object world, not a db one, and it's not needed in object).

Comment: yes RoleInEmployee class does not exist.can we load data on employee object for particular role.can you tell me how to made linq query for that